# Error in Google SignOut process Uncaught Error: nb JS

Tags: javascript, google-signin

Just to make my code refactored I have written google SignOut function as follows

```
function googleSignOut() {
    if (typeof module_google_login == 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
        var gApiAuth = gapi.auth2;
        gApiAuth.init().then(doGoogleLogout(gApiAuth));
    });
};

function doGoogleLogout(gApiAuth) {
    console.log(gApiAuth);
    var googleAuth = gApiAuth.getAuthInstance();
    googleAuth.signOut().then(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/account/logout/',
            success: function () {
                auth2.disconnect();
                window.location = "/account";
            }
        });
    });
}
```

But it gives an error in the console like this

```
Uncaught Error: nb
    at tE (cb=gapi.loaded_0:201)
    at jF.<anonymous> (cb=gapi.loaded_0:248)
    at new _.C (cb=gapi.loaded_0:123)
    at jF.BT (cb=gapi.loaded_0:248)
    at Ay.Qv.a.<computed> [as signOut] (cb=gapi.loaded_0:227)
    at doGoogleLogout (main.js:48)
    at main.js:41
    at platform.js:18
    at Sa (platform.js:10)
    at Y (platform.js:18)
```

But I implement it like this

```
function googleSignOut() {
    if (typeof module_google_login == 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
        gapi.auth2.init().then(function () {
            var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
            auth2.signOut().then(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/account/logout/',
                    success: function () {

                        window.location = "/account";
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
};
```

then it works fine though it does not look that good. If someone can tell me what is wrong with my previous implementation and what that is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with this line 
`gApiAuth.init().then(doGoogleLogout(gApiAuth));`.

For success handler of the promise, you need to pass functional reference not call the function directly. Here `doGoogleLogout(gApiAuth)` will be called before the promise is resolved. Change this to `gApiAuth.init().then(()=>doGoogleLogout(gApiAuth))`

Read more about from this [link](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-promise-27fc71e77261)